# Scala JavaScript Routing Play Framework

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm using Play framework with Scala. I'm facing a weird error and can't figure out what's the solution. The error message is:

> value Track is not a member of object controllers.routes.javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.TrackController.javascriptRoutes"></script>

  @helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
    routes.javascript.Track
  )

def Track(id:Long)= Action {implicit request =>
    Ok(views.html.track(
        new TrackData(TrackClient.getTrack(id))))


  }

 def javascriptRoutes = Action { implicit request =>

 Ok(
         Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")    (routes.javascript.TrackController.Track)).as("text/javascript")
    }
#JavaScriptRouting
GET     /track/:id                  @controllers.TrackController.Track(id: Long)
GET     /javascriptRoutes           @controllers.TrackController.javascriptRoutes
```

The new error is :

```
1@(message: String)

2

3@main("Welcome to Play 2.1") { 

4    

5    @play20.welcome(message)

6    

7}
```

> index.scala.html at line 3.  Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here

It says index.scala but I have never changed it.

Comment: oh, the part you pasted above is in the `main` template? Then all templates that call `@main` need the second parameter list `(implicit request: RequestHeader)`. Here it would be `@(message: String)(implicit request: RequestHeader)`. *edit*: and all controllers that call those templates need the `implicit request =>` at the beginning of the `Action`.

Comment: Okey thank you so much =) i have some other errors now , i will try to solve them

Comment: I have one more problem which is about my tests , now how i can implement this changes (implicit request: RequestHeader) to my tests

Comment: and also @supertrackGraph(data.graph) this line says cannot find any http request header here

Comment: There is a [FakeRequest](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/scala/index.html#play.api.test.FakeRequest) that you can use when testing controllers or views, e.g. `view.html.index(<params>)(FakeRequest())`. For your other error, is `@supertrakGraph(...)` called in a view? Then that one needs an implicit request as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your javascript route is defined as:

```
GET     /javascriptRoutes           controllers.TrackController.javascriptRoutes
```

*Edit*: play uses a special reverse route for javascript, under `routes.javascript`.

so your reverse controller will be at `controllers.routes.javascript.TrackController.Track`:

```
@helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
  routes.javascript.TrackController.Track
)
```

You also need to make an implicit `RequestHeader` available in your template. So add at the beginning of your template:

```
@(implicit request: RequestHeader)
```

Or if you already have template parameters:

```
@(<your parameters>)(implicit request: RequestHeader)
```

And make sure it is available in your controller's `Action`:

```
def myController = Action { implicit request => // <-- request is a RequestHeader
  // ...
  Ok(views.html.myView)
}
```

If that view (let's call it `main`) is called from within another view (let's say `index`), then `index` also needs an implicit `RequestHeader` parameter as well, to be able to pass it down to `main`.

Comment: When i apply this solution the result is :Description Resource Path Location Type
type mismatch;  found   : play.api.mvc.Call  required: play.core.Router.JavascriptReverseRoute main.template.scala /ubit/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/views/html line 48 Scala Problem

Comment: oops, sorry, the router's path was wrong; fixed. You would then run is the same error as with @mohammed-gh's answer. I also added how to solve that.

Comment: okey i am trying to fix that but still the same error : first i did : @(title: String)(content: Html)(implicit request: RequestHeader) and then @helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
  routes.javascript.TrackController.Track
) to somewhere around the head

Comment: Hum, you still get "cannot find HTTP Request Header here"? what about `@helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")( routes.javascript.TrackController.Track)(request)`?

Comment: nope this time i got 6 of them in index.template.scala and 5 other templates on eclipse and when i compile through browser it says : @main("Welcome to Play 2.1") { -<Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here

Comment: Can you update your question with an edit showing what you tried and the result? Doing that in comments isn't very handy.

Answer (score 1):

Because your controller's name is *TrackController*, so try to change this code:

```
@helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
  routes.javascript.Track
)
```

with this:

```
@helper.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")(
  routes.javascript.TrackController.Track
)
```

Comment: When i apply this the error message is :
Cannot find any HTTP Request Header here